# What's all about the process of invoking a file with a mouse click in ubuntu (generally in Linux)?

Tags: mouse, window-manager, desktop-environment, hid

First of all, I apologize for the beginner's question. I still can't think of what's going on in the system (Ubuntu 21.10) after, for example, I click on the "Files" icon and then on a file. What does the process of invoking a file with a mouse click associated with, for example, gedit or invoking a directory or just any program actually contain? Is it written somewhere like in `/proc/bus/input/devices Ev = ...`, what happens to the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking, but roughly:

- The kernel drivers react to hardware events from the mouse and the keyboard
- The various kernel layers translate, say, a mouse click, and put it as mouse event in the kernel input layer. You can read this from `/dev/input/eventX` using `evtest`.
- The X driver (X is the windowing system) translates this into an X event. You can look at those e.g. with `xev`.
- The X server determines which window should receive the event.
- For "click on an icon", the receive is the Window Manager (WM).
- For "click on a file", the receiver is the application that shows the files (whatever this is on your Ubuntu, there's plenty of choice)
- The application decides what to do with the event (pop a window with a director, use a system call to execute a program, etc.)
- `/proc/bus/input/devices` plays not role in this process.

If you want to understand Linux, I strongly suggest learning the command line first. The UI is optional.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I learned exactly what was not clear to me. Is there any fully available literature on these processes in Linux?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any single place where this is described.